# Converting BAT to EXE

Tags: batch-file, exe

I would like to know how to convert a batch file (.bat) to an executable file (.exe). Is there any software I can download to help me with this?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bat2exe/

Comment: You could do this EASILY in iexpress, with a `.inf` file. A simple google seach could produce an answer. Please research before asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok sorry Im new to stackoverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174386/how-can-a-bat-file-be-converted-to-exe-without-third-party-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a program called bat to exe here is the link:www.f2ko.de/programs.php?pid=b2e

Comment: Be aware of coin minser trojans.