# When batch is converted to exe. Nircmd?

Tags: batch-file, exe

If i use NirCMD in my batch file and then convert it to exe, can my friend run it if doesn't have NirCMD?
I want to send him a program that will automatically play songs and turn up or down the volume(that's why I use NirCMD)

This may seem like a noobish question but i want to know the answer.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `nircmd` is an external executable file, it won't be included.

To ship one executable file use any of the following:

- Self-extracting exe using 7-zip or other archiver.
- Pismo Self Mounting Installer/Executable: [more info](http://www.pismotechnic.com/ptsmx/)
- IExpress: [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28174404/3959875)
- Commercial solutions like EXE-Bundle

Comment: so if i include it in exe file and make it extract in C:\windows it will work?

Comment: Both your batch-exe and nircmd.exe are extracted to some predefined folder (for example Windows temporary folder) then it'll execute the file you specified in the options (different solutions provide different methods).