# Opening file in Windows via Script

Tags: c, windows, batch-file

I want to write a script that opens a file in Windows explorer (not just open and read it in cmd, I want it to properly open it like I double clicked it). My first thought was a batch file and it indeed worked, but batch files can be edited and read, and I don't want that. Most batch to .exe converters were marked as viruses so I abandoned the idea and thought of writing a C script and then convert to .exe with codeblocks.

The thing is, I don't know how to open a file in windows explorer from C. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174386/how-can-a-bat-file-be-converted-to-exe-without-third-party-tools)

Comment: Most likely a duplicate so here's just a tip: simply use [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) like `ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "c:\path\file", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: There is not such thing as a C-script.

Comment: C is no scriping language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows I suppose you could use `system`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  system("explorer.exe c:\\path\\to\\file.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

As discussed in the comments a more robust solution would be to use `ShellExecute` as in this example.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ShellApi.h>

void view_file(const char* pszFileName) {
  ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, pszFileName, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);  
}

int main(void) {
  view_file("c:\\path\\to\\file.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to really simulate the default operation when you doubleclick on a file you can pass in `NULL` as the second parameter

> NULL
>
> The default verb is used, if available. If not, the "open" verb is used. If neither verb is available, the system uses the first verb
>   listed in the registry.

Further information about `ShellExecute` can be read in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You might want to use the full path of `explorer.exe` (e.g "c:\\windows\system32\explorer.exe")

Comment: I don't think there's any point, if `C:\windows\system32` isn't in your PATH something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @szczurcio yeah that was my thought aswell. Unless you have a broken registry it should be fine.

Comment: Any why not the actual function that is used by Explorer itself to launch the file - [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @szczurcio: `windir` and `SystemRoot` not necessarily need to reside on drive C:.

Comment: @alk Of course, I was simplifying, but the point still stands: on a normal system it should be in the PATH.

Comment: @wOxxOm Of course `ShellExecute` would be more robust, however since OP seemed to require only a very basic solution I think this will work fine. I'll update my answer though.

Comment: @Linus, the OP wanted to simulate doubleclick, so instead of `"open"` use `NULL` (and maybe add a note from the docs). Because `open` is not necessarily the default action for a file.