# Run a hidden cmd on click

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is driving me crazy. I have a pretty application that does.. well, things. To start it up, some `start.cmd` needs to be executed. What `start.cmd` does is to set up some environment variables, check a few things and then start my main GUI program.

Now, everything works fine: when I click on my `start.cmd` everything gets launched properly. However, clicking on `start.cmd` causes an ugly, ugly `cmd.exe` to appear for an instant and then disappear. This is unacceptable!

I started looking around and I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way). It suggests to use some `wscript invisible.vbs`to run my `start.cmd`. This, however, works fine from the terminal, but I can't click on `invisible.vbs` directly to get what I need.

This is where I thought that I could use shortcut with the `wscript invisible.vbs start.cmd` command in it. However, you cannot make relative path shortcuts in Windows, which means that if I use a shortcut I will never be able to move my folder again, which is pretty bad if I need to install it around my users' computers.

So I really have no clue on how to get this apparently trivial thing done: *how can I get a* `start.cmd` *batch file executed without anything showing **and** without having to launch anything from the terminal, **and** in a way that will allow me to move my folder around?*

Comment: Can you use a shortcut to `wscript.exe` with `invisible.vbs` as the argument?

Comment: Yes I can but I would have to provide as working directory to wscript the folder where my program is. I would then need to know its absolute path, which would mean that it would be impossible to move my folder without breaking the shortcut. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [hidder.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/iexpress/hidder.bat) . You can use it to wrap a `.bat` or `.exe` file into iexpress executable file that will be ran in hidden mode.To use you need:

```
hidder.bat example.bat hiddenExample.exe
```

this line will create a `hiddenExample.exe` which clicked will start your bat in hidden/background mode.You can also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174386/how-can-a-bat-file-be-converted-to-exe-without-third-party-tools)

Comment: This would have been exactly what I would need! However. this doesn't seem to work. I made an example `test.bat` script with `ECHO mytest > test.txt` in it. If I click it, a `test.txt` file appears with `mytest` in it. Now I run `hidder.bat test.bat test.exe`. Some `test.exe` is generated. If I click on it, however, nothing happens at all. I am using Windows 10... could this be a problem?

Comment: @MatteoMonti - iexpress executes its post-extraction commands in directories like `%temp%\IXPXXX.TMP` (but not in the current directory) and when it's finished the folder is deleted. You can't pass arguments to the created exe. So in your bat you'll need to hardcode the path to the file you want to output to.E.g `echo test>%temp%\mytestFile.txt`

Comment: Which brings me back to the previous problem, that I would never be able to move my folder! Too bad!