# How to convert .bat to .exe without the antivirus blocking it

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

I have a very basic batch file, and it has only one line(for example):

```
echo hello world
```

I was searching for a program to convert this small file, to a windows executable(.exe), and I found two famous programs, one is called "BAT TO EXE CONVERTOR by F2KO"(http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) , and the second one is called "Advanced BAT to EXE convertor"(http://www.battoexeconverter.com/).

I downloaded both, and it worked! it actually converted to EXE! the only problem is, that my antivirus is blocking the EXE file(and deleting it everytime, I do something with it, even when I add an exception for that file on my antivirus, its still going to work only on my pc).

I want to convert the file, becuase I made a game with java, and I made it executable jar, and because I wanted to run this jar file, I needed to create a batch file, that will call the jar file and execute it.
but if I will upload my game somewhere as a batch file, and just say "it is a game", I afraid that people won't believe me..

Is there any way, to convert the file, and send it to other people, without the antivirus blocking the file?

Comment: Normally, you would add an exception in your antivirus. That said, don't convert batch scripts to exe. The script just gets extracted to some system directory and run as a regular batch script anyway. Use a language that actually compiles if you want to hide your code.

Comment: im sorry, i will explain a bit more @SomethingDark

Comment: Plenty of games use batch scripts. It's not your fault that there are idiots in the Internet who can't read.

Comment: oh.. so I understand that there is no solution for that.. you are correct though, thank you very much for your support anyway :) @SomethingDark

Comment: Seriously, though, you should be able to just add an exception in your antivirus to allow the file.

Comment: But as I said before, if I will add an exception in my antivirus, it will affect only my computer, and I want to upload the program to GitHub and to my friend. and I don't want just to say everybody to add an exception. that's the problem

Comment: Only an imbecile would run an `.exe` just because they were told it was a game, at least as a batch file the end user can read it in plain text and generally understand what will happen when it is invoked.

Comment: Whether or not their antivirus picks up your exe file is completely dependent on what antivirus they're using. You can upload the file to a site like VirusTotal to show them it's fine.

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174386/how-can-a-bat-file-be-converted-to-exe-without-third-party-tools) ?

Comment: wow it works!! @npocmaka thank you very much bud! and thanks everybody for helping :D