# obfuscating batch+HTA hybrid script

Tags: batch-file, obfuscation, hta

Following is the hybrid batch script:

```html
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
setlocal

echo Select an option:
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do set "HTAreply=%%a"
echo End of HTA window, reply: "%{HTAreply}%"
pause
goto :EOF
-->


<HTML>
<HEAD>
<HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="no" SYSMENU="no" >

<TITLE>HTA Buttons</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
window.resizeTo(374,100);

function closeHTA(reply){
   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   fso.GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(reply);
   window.close();
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
   <button onclick="closeHTA(1);">First option</button>
   <button onclick="closeHTA(2);">Second option</button>
   <button onclick="closeHTA(3);">Third option</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Output:
[image]

I obfuscated it as stated here : [Post#21]
https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7990&start=15

but then the HTA app output isn't as before. It is as follows:
[image]
The entire batch content is displayed in the HTML window.

I want to know why this happens and secondly is there any way to obfuscate this hybrid batch script
Same happens when I try to convert the batch file to exe.

**Edit**

Problem solved. There was an error in html code. apologies. I would have edited to show the problem but I guess it was too trivial to do that.

Comment: You obfuscated batch, which means it stills valid in batch. However your source is mixed batch/html. HTML obfuscated as batch in not valid HTML.

Comment: update : I tried taking the html code into .hta file and then called it in batch, it works fine except that I'm passing a batch variable to .hta as this - 'echo UserID^| mshta "D:temp:test.hta" the only problem now is it doesn't show the passed user value in html window. This question  is more of how to pass value to hta app when the hta file is no longer a part of the batch file. Obfuscating works fine now

Comment: Why would you post a question about this over here when the Developer of Obfuscate.bat is very active on the DosTips forums where the code is maintained and questions are answered.

Comment: I would have but the question is now a different one. please refer above comment

Comment: @Abhi, I will completely disagree with you. The only person who is going to know the answer to using Obfuscate.bat with your Hybrid code is the developer.

Comment: @Abhi and you also started another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788517/edit-a-obfuscated-a-batch-file)

Comment: @Squashman - you should take the time to read it first. LS_dev already hinted at the probable solution by giving the reason...so it&amp;#39;s not an obfuscate issue! So to repeat for Ur Convince..just took the html code into an .hta file and called it in batch ...ok ? Inshort this has Nothing to do with that forum or the method or expertise that guy had in obfuscation

Comment: @Squashman The only thing the other question u pointed out is obfuscate...it&#39;s totally different. Also for your convenience..I repeat it wasn&#39;t an obfuscate issue..as was hinted by ls_dev ..So i took the html code in hta file and called this hta all inside batch file

Comment: If you can't even edit your question to show what the actual problem was, then either post the solution as an answer and mark it accepted or delete this question since it will help literally nobody else.

Comment: I had edited it to be deleted..the mod chose to instead put it as an update. It&#39;s not relevant editing because it is no longer related to the original problem

Comment: There's a delete button at the bottom of your question. Click it.

Comment: Don&#39;t u think I tried that...I can&#39;t delete a post...it goes for review after I do that..that&#39;s what I did as I said above already