# Cannot send arguments to batch file converted to application via IExpress

Tags: batch-file, iexpress

I have made a batch file which contains personal data, so to hide it from other people and to post it, I decided to "encrypt" it converting it to `exe` via IExpress.

My batch file is named `prime.bat` and it is located in `%userprofile%`.

Here are the steps I ran with `iexpress.exe`:

- Runned `iexpress.exe`.
- Selected `Create new Self Extraction Directive file`
- Selected `Extract files and run an installation command`.
- Entered package title (`Prime finder`).
- Selected `No prompt.`.
- Selected `Do not display a license.`.
- Selected `prime.bat` located in `%userprofile%` (`C:\Users\%username%`).
- Entered `cmd /c prime.bat` in `Install Program` and left `Post Install Command` as is (`<None>`).
- Selected `Default (recommended)`.
- Selected `No message`.
- Entered `C:\Users\username\prime.exe` and did not check any of boxes below.
- Selected `No restart`.
- Selected to save `SED` file.

**Package created successfully!**

---

As the batch file works with arguments, it **must** be run from the cmd. When I clicked the file single from explorer it opened correctly. Because I had put an error message if there are no arguments, it threw expected error and exited with `1`. If I type just `prime.exe` in cmd, the above happens, and same output is produced.

---

**But**, if I run file from cmd again, but **specify** arguments, I get an error message in a new window. As I don't use English language and do not have the permissions to change language, I will try to translate the output:

> Syntax error appeared in command line's selections.
>
> Type `/?` after the command for help.

So, I typed `prime.exe /?`, and a new window with help appeared. I think I am missing something in `iexpress.exe` options.

Comment: This topic has been covered a few times on StackOverFlow and I am almost certain you cannot pass arguments to the bat file once it is packed up with Iexpress.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174386/how-can-a-bat-file-be-converted-to-exe-without-third-party-tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem using:

```
prime.exe /c:"cmd /c prime.bat numeric_arguments"
```

Which should be used when you want to send arguments to an IExpress 'compiled' file as `/c` option specifies a new install command.